# Bash Game Scorefile

Tags: bash, sed

I'm working on a simple number guessing game (to boost my bash skills) which at the end appends score and name to a file and then displays it to the player, like so:

```
10 Hana 
10 lilka 
10 nogba 
12 nogba 
13 Hana 
13 ugaea 
1 Lilka 
5 lilka 
7 borja 
7 Hana 
8 frina 
8 molaa 
9 Hana 
9 lanma 
9 lilka
```

Before displaying the high score file I'd like to remove all duplicate lines but leave the ones with the lowest score. Like so:

```
10 nogba 
13 ugaea 
1 Lilka 
5 lilka 
7 borja 
7 Hana 
8 frina 
8 molaa 
9 lanma
```

I'm thinking sed could be my answer but i'm not shure.

Maybe something like this?

```
echo $highscorevalue >> $scorefile
sed -i '$!N; /^\(.*\)\n\1$/!P; D' $scorefile
cat $scorefile | sort
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with `awk` as well:

```
awk '{if($1 < a[$2] || !a[$2]) a[$2]=$1} END{for(i in a) print a[i], i}' file
```

This will fill an array `a` with the minimal value value in the first column for each name of the second column. The array is displayed at the end.

Note the output is not sorted. If you want to sort it, add `| sort -k2` to the command.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sort -n -k2,2 -k1,1 score.txt | awk '!seen[$2]++' | sort
10 nogba 
13 ugaea 
1 Lilka 
5 lilka 
7 borja 
7 Hana 
8 frina 
8 molaa 
9 lanma
```

- The first `sort` command sorts by second column and then numerically sort in ascending order when there are multiple entries for a name.
- The `awk` command discards duplicates based on names in second column, keeping the first entry
- Second `sort` command used only to match output as given in question